# What is the root place of FileReader searching for files?

Tags: java

I've tried to load file to use by scanner like this:

```
try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("map.txt"));
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I get the FileNotFoundException error even thought I place map.txt file in class folder. Also I created special folder and marked it as a resources root in IntelliJ IDEA but still it doesn't work. How can I know where FileReader is searching for file then?

Comment: You application has a current working directory. Just like your command prompt has a current working directory.  This is the starting point for relative paths.  This is not specific to Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help you. Use [File#getAbsolutePath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29) to check for the path.

```
File reader = new File("abc.txt");
System.out.println(reader.getAbsolutePath());
```

Some more ways to read from project

```
// Read from resources folder parallel to src in your project
File file1 = new File("resources/abc.txt");
System.out.println(file1.getAbsolutePath());

// Read from src/resources folder
File file2 = new File(getClass().getResource("/resources/abc.txt").toURI());
System.out.println(file2.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: It did help. FileReader was searching in project folder, not in src floder, where classes were, nor the new created Resources folder witch I've marked as a resources root.

Comment: Try other option that I have mentioned or create a resources folder under src folder of the project.